# Why does sequenceA need Traversable?

Tags: haskell

From the [Typeclassopedia](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia):

> ```
> sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
> ```
>
> Takes a list of computations and combines them into one computation which collects a list of their results. It is again something of a historical accident that sequence has a `Monad` constraint, since it can actually be implemented only in terms of `Applicative`.

And indeed, there is `sequenceA` which operates on `Applicative` types.

```haskell
sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
```

But wait, why does `sequenceA` need the `Traversable` constraint when it can be implemented without it?

```haskell
seqA :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]
seqA = foldr fx (pure [])
         where
           fx f fs = pure (:) <*> f <*> fs)
```

Comment: Your `seqA` only works with lists, while `sequenceA` can deal with any `Traversable`, including lists (note the constraints in the signature are on different type variables, `f` and `t`).

Comment: [facepalm] Right, of course! Totally missed the `t (f a)` versus `[f a]` distinction...

Comment: @duplode Put that in an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a subject that can be initially confusing because there is a lot of history and change around it, and older explanations are out of date.  The history is roughly this:

1. The idea of the `sequence` operation dates back to the 1990s, when the `Monad` class was incorporated into Haskell and people first formulated generic operations for it.  The signature that you quote from the Typeclassopedia reflects this: `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`.  It can work with any monad, but it is hardcoded to work on lists.
2. The `Applicative` class was developed during the mid-to-late 2000s; the seminal paper that everybody cites is McBride and Patterson (2008), ["Applicative Programming with Effects"](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html).  McBride and Patterson also note that:

   - The old monadic `sequence` operation can in fact be generalized to `dist :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]`.  The `Monad` constraint is too narrow!
   - Likewise, the old `mapM` function (close relative to `sequence`) generalizes to `traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]`.
   - This can be generalized to non-list data structures by putting these operations into a `Traversable` class that they propose in the paper.
3. The `Applicative` and `Traversable` classes were added into the GHC `base` libraries, with some small changes.  The `dist` function was named `sequenceA` instead, and the `Foldable` class joined `Traversable` for types that support only a subset of `Traversable`'s requirements.
4. These classes proved extremely popular.  But that shows that the original  `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` signature was **wrong in hindsight**.
5. So finally, fast-forward to 2015, when GHC implemented the [Applicative/Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal) (make `Applicative` a superclass of `Monad`) and the [Foldable/Traversable Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude), where the base libraries were revised in order to get them close to the ideal, hindsight-informed design.

The Foldable/Traversable Proposal, however, did not change the signature of `sequence`.  I can't tell you precisely why, but the answer is going to be some obtuse detail that boils down to historical reasons, backward compatibility or something like that.  But I can tell you that if we could start all over again:

1. `sequence` would have `sequenceA`'s signature;
2. `sequenceA` would not exist independently of `sequence`;
3. `mapM` is just `traverse` with the wrong signature, and thus would not exist independently either.